# Continuous updates from server on database change to my web page

Tags: java

I need to develop a webpage which will keep showing latest database value without refreshing the page.
After searching a lot, I got that this can be done by using servlet 3.0 asynchronous support.
But I am not able to get a pretty much help that how can I implement this on my web page.
Any kind of suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered just making Ajax calls?

Comment: Yeah!!.. I know that ajax calls will do, but they will not make server push. With this every time I have to make a request to get a response. But I need that whenever any changes are made to database, they should be pushed by server to my web page without making a request.

Comment: The problem is that the server can not identify a particular client, so mostly all HTTP transactions are client initiated. If you are interested you should read about push notification mechanism in protocols like ActiveSync.

Comment: You can look for Comet implementations in Java. Tomcat has support for Comet https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html.
Websockets(yes, it's HTML5) can also be used.

Answer (score 0):

The below code may be helpful to you.

```
$.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                async: true,
                url:ActionName,
                dataType:"json",
                success: function(data){ 
                  $("#result").empty();
                  $("#result").html();

                },


          error:function(){

                    }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..But I need help on server side coding too.